# Adjusting a Mixer Tap Hot/Cold Mix

Tags: plumbing, water, taps

I have a Twyford mixer tap on my bathroom washbasin ([Exact model here](http://www.twyfordbathrooms.com/Products/Brassware/Basin%20Monobloc/aq5126.aspx)).

As it stands the Hot/Cold mix I can get out of it is either very hot or very cold, with a tiny area in the middle giving a suitable temperature. While this is workable for adult,my 3 year old son invariably has to wash his hands in cold water, and risks burning himself.

The shower works off the same hot and cold supply, and we can get a very satisfactory mix easily, so I was assuming it was something to do with the tap adjustment.

We do not have the original fitting instructions, and have emailed the supplier for a copy, however I was wondering if there was anything I could do for myself.

I have worked out that its possible to pop off the plastic cosmetic cover on the front of the tap, as shown below:

[image: Tap1]

This gives me access to a nut inside which I can undo wit an allen key, as shown below:

[image: Tap2]

However, after this I am at a loss of what to do. The top of the tap still seems firmly in place - I don't want to force it in case I break it.

I am assuming of course that this gives me access to some sort of adjustment mechanism - I could, of course be wrong.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What are you expecting when you open this? Are you planning to modify the valve or do you think there's a switch to make it less hot? What's the temperature of your hot water (fill a bucket with water and use a meat thermometer)? Also, do you have a dishwasher?

Comment: I have a shower valve that has as similar problem. In my case the valve does not smoothly move through the mix temperature range. Just a small movement can cause quite a shift in temperature. I believe that the fix for my case is to replace the inner rubber seals in the valve - a job I have been putting off for some time now.

Comment: I guess I don't know. I had assumed that something in the tap would help me adjust moderate the temperature. Assume I know nothing and am just clutching at straws. Yes I do have a dishwasher, but they are different supplies - the dishwater is on mains, and the tap runs off a tank in the attic.

Comment: Is there a noticeable pressure difference between the hot and cold water?

Comment: And as for removing the handle it will provide access to the mixer Cartridge which is non serviceable in most new taps and even if it is its not worth the trouble as you can just buy a new cartridge to replace it if you want.

Comment: Reason for the questions is that you may be better off reducing the temperature on your hot water heater. With a dishwasher, it needs to be hot to dissolve the detergent (140F is a good temp). With kids or elderly, 120F is better to reduce the risk of scalding, but don't go much lower since some diseases grow at 110F.

Comment: BMitch may have the best suggestion, it is the nature of some taps to not have much useful range of adjustment. Lowering the temperature will increase the range and remove the scalding danger. If it was always like this, changing the cartridge probably will not help, the only other viable solution is to replace the tap for a model with better adjustment.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. Looks like I'll be reducing the temperature of the water on the boiler then.